# How to auto run .env file with dbt?

Tags: shell, dbt

Is there a plugin or some utility to auto-run .env files with dbt? Currently, I am running
`set -o allexport; source .env; set +o allexport`. I would like to have all the environment variables auto-exported when I execute a dbt command. Is there a way to do this that is standard with DBT? I understand I could decorate the dbt command in my shell profile (e.g. ~/.zprofile) but I would prefer to use a standard solution if there is one.

Comment: Adding support for `dbt.env` is considered https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/6207